# Keep users age up to date in Firebase with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, datepicker, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app with user registration and I'm using Firebase as my backend.

I have used a date picker to allow the user to select their age and now I want to find out if there is a way for the age to be automatically updated in Firebase? It seems a bit tedious to do it manually.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Why not store a birth date instead of a fixed age? Then you can calculate the current age as needed for display in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase does not offer an option to run code in the background.

If you still want your data to be updated without any kind of user actions, you could use cloud services like Google Cloud Platform with its App Engine to run code from there, which updates all user ages according to the current year.

Google has some handy documentation on [just such an environment](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services#firebase-appengine-standard).

> ### Firebase and Google App Engine standard environment
>
> App Engine standard environment is an application platform that 
>   monitors, updates, and scales the hosting environment; all you need to 
>   do is write your mobile backend service code.
>
> If your app needs to process user data or orchestrate events, extending 
>   Firebase with App Engine standard environment gives you the benefit of 
>   automatic real-time data synchronization
>
> ### Recommended for:
>
> - Firebase apps that need a backend service to modify the synchronized data.
> - Backend services that run periodically to process or analyze Firebase data.
>
> ### Not recommended for:
>
> - Backend services that call native binaries, write to the file system, or make other system calls.
> - Persistent connections to Firebase. App Engine standard environment reclaims socket connections after 2 minutes.